# Adding Attachment to Work Item through custom Widget Using ajax call

Tags: azure-devops

How to Add Attachment to Work Item through custom Widget using ajax call. I read about API call but did not understand how it would be done, through ajax I am able to create the work item using my widget, but unable to add attachment to it. Find my ajax code below:

$("#btnAttachment").click(function () {

```
    var restURL = "https://dev.azure.com/organizationName/{" + VSS.getWebContext().project.id + "}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName='C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\picturemessage_4hm34b3k.kot.png'&api-version=5.0";

    var myPatToken = "xyz";

    $.ajax({

        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',

        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + myPatToken)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Failure");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.responseText));
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: restURL
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried? what is "did not work" - did you get an error?

Comment: Please find the code added above in the question.